# Build a new Grails app by Gradle

Tags: grails, gradle

I get a company's project from Github, and import into the GGTS as a gradle project. Everything runs OK. [gradle task show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPbLS.png).

I want to create a new Grails app, so I used the command `grails create-app wtf`, and then import into GGTS as a Gradle project. What make me confused is that the file named `build.gradle` or the folder named .gradle do not appear, [gradle task shows null like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ8t8.png), while I do the same thing in system of company and it runs fine.

Please tell me what happend? And I did not write a build.gradle in system of company manually.

Comment: Which version of Grails did you use when running the create-app command?

Comment: Grails version is 2.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Grails 2.4.4 does not use Gradle. That didn't start until Grails 3.0.

I *believe* you need to import the project as a Grails project (I haven't used ggts in a long time, so my recollection it's foggy). You can read more about IDE integration [here.](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/gettingStarted.html#ide)

Comment: Yes,the grails version of ggts is obsolete,and the `grails-3.1.1` runs fine. Thank you!